Crystal Reports in ASP.NET app showing 'Could not load file or assembly' when trying to use Windows impersonation
In my ASP.NET app, all Crystal Reports that are set to use Windows impersonation result in 'Could not load file or assembly'.
However, Crystal Reports that are set to use a hard coded SQL user in the Web.config file run OK.
How can set the Crystal Reports to run as the user's Windows user?
My Web.config file is currently:
...
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <!--<authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>-->
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <!--<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>-->
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <!--<add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>-->
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <!--<remove name="StaticCompressionModule" />-->
      <!--<remove name="DynamicCompressionModule" />-->
      <!--<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />-->
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <!--<applicationInitialization
      remapManagedRequestsTo="Startup.htm"
      skipManagedModules="true">
      <add initializationPage="/Home/Index"/>
    </applicationInitialization>-->
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.4000.0" newVersion="13.0.4000.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.4000.0" newVersion="13.0.4000.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.4000.0" newVersion="13.0.4000.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.4000.0" newVersion="13.0.4000.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.4000.0" newVersion="13.0.4000.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.4000.0" newVersion="13.0.4000.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.4000.0" newVersion="13.0.4000.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.4000.0" newVersion="13.0.4000.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.4000.0" newVersion="13.0.4000.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.4000.0" newVersion="13.0.4000.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.4000.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.4000.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="0">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myAppInsightsListener" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>



